# How does recursion work in this quick sort program?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, quicksort

This is a code for sorting array elements using Quick Sort..

```cpp
void QuickSort(int a[], int beg, int end)
{
    if(beg<end)
    {
        int p=Partition(a,beg,end);                       
        QuickSort(a,beg,p-1);                           
        QuickSort(a,p+1,end);                        
    }
}
```

you can observe:

```cpp
int p=Partition(a,beg,end);                      
QuickSort(a,beg,p-1);                             
QuickSort(a,p+1,end);
```

I haven't understood in this function how those recursive calls are working, how the partitioned array is given to `QuickSort(a,beg,p-1);` and `QuickSort(a,p+1,end);`. I end up in between and when I dry run or debug it, I get confused as it looks like a merge sort. Also I know visual representation of Quick Sort (saw on youtube).

Can anyone explain to me by taking x[5] all the iterations?

```cpp
#include<iostream>

#include<time.h>

using namespace std;
int z = 0;
int Partition(int a[], int beg, int end) //Function to Find Pivot Point
{
  int p = beg, pivot = a[beg], loc;
  for (loc = beg + 1; loc <= end; loc++) {
    if (pivot > a[loc]) {
      a[p] = a[loc];
      a[loc] = a[p + 1];
      a[p + 1] = pivot;
      p = p + 1;
    }
  }
  return p;
}

void QuickSort(int a[], int beg, int end) {
  if (beg < end) {
    int p = Partition(a, beg, end); //Calling Procedure to Find Pivot
    QuickSort(a, beg, p - 1); //Calls Itself (Recursion)
    QuickSort(a, p + 1, end); //Calls Itself (Recursion)
  }
}
int function_Random(int x[1000], int i) {
  if (i == 1001)
    return 0;
  x[z] = rand() % 100;
  cout << x[z] << "\t";
  z++;
  function_Random(x, i += 1);
  //return x;
}
int main() {
  int s;
  static int i;
  int x[1000];
  begin = clock();
  function_Random(x, i);
  QuickSort(x, 0, 1000);

  cout << "\n\nAfter";
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    cout << "\t" << x[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the exact concern is, but it might help if you think of QuickSort in a very high level view.

Quicksort works by selecting an element as the pivot and reordering the elements in the sequence into two subsequences, of smaller and larger values, separated by the pivot. At this point the pivot is in place and you only need to sort both sequences independently.

The heavy work is done by partition that goes over the sequence separating the original sequence into the two subsequences and yielding the final location of the pivot.  Note that after partition completes, the pivot is in it's final location, it need not be moved.

In your case the pivot is selected as the first element, so you would have:

```
initial:     [ pivot, other elements... ]
partitioned: [ smaller..., pivot, larger... ]
```

At this point you quicksort the subsequences `[ smaller... ]` and `[ larger... ]`.

Note that this is not like mergesort, in mergesort you have a fixed split point, you sort both subsequences independently and then build the overall solution by merging the results. In quicksort you pick an element move it to the right location separating the universe into smaller/larger values that form the two subsequences, the split point is determined by the value of the pivot and the relative values of all other elements.

Comment: Alright : consider int p=Partition(a,beg,end);   = P
                QuickSort(a,beg,p-1);                       =Q1
                QuickSort(a,p+1,end);                       =Q2

now [ 3 2 4 1 5] now calling seq will be P Q1 P Q1 P afterwards what happens I am not getting and how array is getting updated?

Comment: @Ruchir: What is the input sequence? If the input sequence is `[ 3 2 4 1 5 ]` and you choose `3` as the pivot (first element) partition will complete with `[ {1 2} 3 {4 5} ]` and the location of `3`. Where `{1 2}` means any combination (either `1 2` or `2 1`, partition does not provide any guarantee as of what order will be given).

Comment: In quicksort you pick an element move it to the right location separating the universe into smaller/larger values that form the two subsequences, the split point is determined by the value of the pivot and the relative values of all other elements : This line I understand visually but inside code when I dry run I am getting wrong outputs.

Comment: @Ruchir: That probably means that there is a bug in the implementation, create a test case, and run it with pen and paper... it seems that the problem is not understanding the algorithm or recursion, but how to debug a broken implementation. I could take a look and try to find what the bug is, but that won't help you learn how to do it for any other problem. Pen and paper is a good mechanism to understand what it should be doing, adding print statements dumping the data at specific points and checking that against your intended goal should lead you to the solution.

Comment: I would provide a set of tests for partition to ensure that it does what it should. That function is not recursive, the implementation should be simple and verifying the input/output pairs should be a simple task. Then you can figure out why you are not getting the right output from the function.  Testing is also a big part of programming, and you will need to write meaningful tests that help finding issues and in debugging them.

Comment: @ David Rodríguez Thanks for all your help if you want I will cout<< some debug and post it in comments but comment will not work as it will increase size of it  and Add Comment button will get disabled so where should I post the debug? I am new here.

Comment: @Ruchir: I don't want the printouts, *you* want them to debug your problem. I gave you a couple of pointers on how to proceed from here and I will *not* debug your problem (it would probably take me a couple of minutes, which is not much, but it will *hurt* you by not letting you learn an important part of the craft)

Comment: @ David Rodríguez : as I explained in my discussion that I have dry run this program it means--> use of pen and paper and I am unable to conclude any thing

Comment: @Ruchir: Really, build a couple of test cases for partition, verify that it breaks the sequence as expected and that it returns the appropriate values, or fix the code if it doesn't.  I might not have made myself clear on what I meant with pen and paper: draw the input, execute mentally instruction after instruction drawing the state of the program (what each value represents graphically), do this for a couple of different examples that have different patterns (already sorted, inversely sorted, couple of random cases)... That will lead to your understanding

Comment: You are great  David Rodrígue Thanks for the help Bro.